# Integrating Polymer application with ExpressJS application

Tags: express, polymer

I use ExpressJS to build an application and after trying different frontend frameworks (vue and angular) I settled on google Polymer. I integrated the polymer app by including all the Polymer files in the Expressjs public folder (every file including package.json) and it works fine with my api routes.

Now my question is regarding this approach:
1-Is it safe to include it in the expressjs public folder? It's just html, css and js files.
2-If there is a better setup. What would be a better setup?

I hope someone out there with good experience and enough knowledge could share some practical advice with me. Please be a little specific and if you can share an application folder structure so I can understand it visually.

Comment: Serving your static files (Polymer app in this case) through Express is an acceptable way of handling it. Another option would be using NGINX or Apache to serve the static content and let Express handle the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be safe, because Polymer is a client-side Framework, which means that all of its files have to be public anyway, but usually you serve the build-version of your project (Run "polymer build" with the options you need), which doesn't contain all the config-files (like package.json).